# AngularJS: push() method List object and its nested object

Tags: angularjs

I tried to use the push method in order to save an object and its nested object but I have a little problem with the list.

In this form I have 'Products' and 'Category' but when I fill the form and then  press 'Save' in order to save the 'Product 6' object the 'Category name' doesn't appear in the list and I need to reload the page.

As you can see the category name is empty.

[image]

How can I list the object and its nested object by using the push method?

*Form registration*

```
<form name="newProductForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label> 
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="product.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label> 
        <input type="number" data-ng-model="product.quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label data-for="category">Category:</label>
        <select data-ng-model="product.category.id" class="form form-control">
            <option value="">--Select category--</option>
            <option data-ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addProduct(product)">Save</button>
</form>
```

*Products list*

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="product in products">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.category.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

*Service and Controller*

```
.controller("productsController", function($scope, $http, addProductService, listProductsService, listCategoriesService){

    $scope.addProduct = function(product){
        var newProduct = addProductService.createProduct($scope.product);
        $scope.products.push(newProduct);
    };

    $scope.products = listProductsService.query();
    $scope.categories = listCategoriesService.query();

})

.factory("addProductService", function($resource){
    return $resource("product", {}, {
        createProduct: {
            method: "POST"
        }
    })
})

.factory("listProductsService", function($resource){
        return $resource("product", {}, {
            listProducts: {
                method: "GET"
            }
        })
})
```

Comment: What does `addProductService.createProduct()` do? Does it return a value immediately or is the return the result of a promise? If you put a `console.log(newProduct)` right underneath the line where you are calling `createProduct()` do you get `undefined` in the console?

Comment: @wilson, please show the html for the Products List table.

Comment: @big_water sure, question already updated

Comment: @wilson, thanks, see my other comment on my answer below please.

Comment: @Lex I have added the 'addProductService' service to the question and I get the object in the console.

Comment: @wilson, when you expand the object in the console, does the "category" property in that object have data?  For example, does it have the "category.name" property populated?

Comment: @big_water The object only has the 'category.id' when I change the {{product.category.name}} to {{product.category.id}} the list works fine.

Comment: @wilson, your problem is likely that the server is not populating the category object properly in the data that it is returning.  It should return all of the object properties (name, id, etc.) instead it is only returning Id.  Can you post your server side code for the "createProduct" action? Otherwise, since you have all of the categories in $scope.categories, you could search them by Id and add the right category to your new product object.  But this is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) on $resource:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data.

I believe your code should be similar to:

```
$scope.addProduct = function(product){
    addProductService.createProduct($scope.product, function(newProduct){
        $scope.products.push(newProduct);
    });
};
```

This should wait for the resource method to return then push the returned data onto the array instead of an empty reference.

Comment: Okay but as I said before I can't list the category name after save the object.

Comment: @wilson, when you look at the data returned from the server, does it have the "product.category" object populated with data?